# Is there a way to activate the correct trigger from a user query stored as a string in a bot variable?

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

I am trying to make a bot using the Bot Framework **Composer** that can store user's favorite queries in an array and run them in kind of a speed dial format.

For example, if a person stores "Tell me the weather" on index 3 of the list, then typing "run fav 3" should be same as typing the earlier.

I am able to get access to the array but how can I activate the correct trigger from the query stored in the array?

Comment: are you able to get the value stored in the array

Comment: Yes, I am able to store the values in the array.

Comment: Check the condition based on the result  , Use the "Emit custom event" and trigger the event

Comment: I am using LUIS to trigger an event. How will I check the condition without LUIS?